# appendChild error

Tags: soundcloud

Not quite sure if I understand why simpliest HTML gives me this error:
Line: 1
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Sound Cloud demo</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'DMAlex'
});

SC.stream("/test", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});

function SoundCloudCheck(){
alert('Ponit 1');

SC.stream("/test", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});


alert('Ponit 2');

var track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood';
SC.oEmbed(track_url, { auto_play: true }, function(oEmbed) {
  console.log('oEmbed response: ' + oEmbed);
});

}
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
Calling local application demo
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click me" NAME="Clk"  onclick="SoundCloudCheck();" >
</BODY>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

SC.connect(function() {

```
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 

  });
```

seemed to get rid of the error.

Comment: Right. Doesn't play anything though.

Comment: I wonder do I need to call SC.initialize() with redirection for that? I just need a way to play sound in background (no visible interface) from public tracks.